# How to define a polymorphic (parameterised) GraphQL type?

Tags: graphql

I'd like all my `Mutation` methods to return a result that implements `MutationResult` type:

```
interface MutationResult {
  errors: [UserError]!
}
```

Example:

```
type AuthenticateMutationResult implements MutationResult {
  errors: [UserError]!
  user: User
}

type Mutation {
  authenticate (
    email: String!
    password: String!
  ): AuthenticateMutationResult!
}
```

Creating `...MutationResult` for each mutation would create a lot of boilerplate code.

Is there a way to define a configurable type, e.g.

```
type MutatationResult<fieldName, fieldType> = {
  [fieldName: fieldName]: fieldType
};
```

which would allow me to inline mutation result type:

```
type Mutation {
  authenticate (
    email: String!
    password: String!
  ): MutatationResult<'user', User>!
}
```

Does a syntax for polymorphic types exist in [graphql](/questions/tagged/graphql)?